# How to display one controller value into other controller

Tags: angularjs

i have two different controller "first" and "second" and two different application variable "fname" and "lname" both application variable exist in different controller. i bind the value of application variable in

tag using expression. in second controller i use  "{{ fname + "" +lname}}

" this statement for combining both controller application variable. i can't  get the first controller application variable value in second....what's wrong in my code please share your idea two solve this porblem

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
        myapp.controller("first", function($scope){
            $scope.fname = "smith";
        })
        myapp.controller("second", function ($scope) {
            $scope.lname = "larbth";
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" >
        <div ng-controller="first">
            <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" />
            <p>my name is: {{ fname }}</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="second">
            <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="lname" ng-click=""/>
            <p>last name is: {{ lname }}</p>
            <p >{{ fname + "" +lname}}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Your second controller doesn't have access to `fname` variable. Can you merge these two controllers to one?

Comment: What is your real use-case? Why do you have two controllers? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @AranS if i merge both controllers its easy for me. but i want in this way  how  one controller get the other controller application variable

Comment: simply trying how controller gets the application variable of other controller and bind the value into the  controller @JBNizet

Comment: The appropriate solution depends on the actual use-case. As is your question is too broad. If you want a good answer, ask a good, precise question.

Comment: take first controller application variable and display in second controller like i previously trying to display         <p >{{ fname + "" +lname}}</p> i think only display is simply to understand @JBNizet

Comment: If you don't want to collaborate, then why should I? I don't have any problem. Based on what you provided as information, my answer would be: don't define two controllers, but just one.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when two controllers need to share data it is done through a service.  Your example is a bit contrived and difficult to see why you wouldn't need just one controller.  However, assuming you are just looking for a simple example imagine a login capability.  One controller determines somehow what the currently logged in user is and sets it.  Another controller displays the currently logged in user.  To communicate between the two we'll use a login service...

```
<div ng-cloak ng-app="soExample">
  <div ng-controller="enterLogin">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input ng-model="name" type="text" id="name" />
    <button ng-click="doLogin()">Login</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="displayLogin">
    <p>Currently logged in as {{loginService.loggedInName}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

angular.module("soExample", [])
  .factory("loginService", function() {
    var loggedInName = "";
    return {
      loggedInName: loggedInName
    };
  }).controller("enterLogin", ["$scope", "loginService", function($scope, loginService) {
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        loginService.loggedInName = $scope.name;
    };
  }])
  .controller("displayLogin", ["$scope", "loginService", function($scope, loginService) {
    $scope.loginService = loginService;
  }]);
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/westonpace/pen/jrPXaR)

Comment: This will work, but it's not a good practice. Services should be generally stateless, not used for sharing global data.

Comment: Interesting.  Because the last time I answered a question like this I suggested putting the global data in a top level scope and I was told to put it in a service.  A logged in user is context about the server connection and a cross cutting concern.  Why shouldn't it be put in a dependency injected service?  $locale keeps track of the current locale id.  This seems very similar to me.  This is why I created a different example rather than use the one from the question.  It is not justifiable in every case but I feel like this one makes sense.

Comment: @Pace services are meant to share data. GBa is wrong on that topic.+1

Comment: Scopes (usually on controllers these days) are meant to store data. Services are meant to perform operations on the data. https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/03/five-ways-to-write-better-angular-services/ . There's a reason global variables are frowned upon in most languages.

Comment: That is a good article but every point he makes about services being stateless also applies to using higher level scopes.  All UI applications should be stateless where possible.  Their main goal should be to reflect the server state and not contain its own state.  However, there are some cases (e.g. logged in user, caching search data between views, session management, etc.) where the UI client does have state.  In these cases I think putting them in services is far preferable to putting them in top level scopes.  As you said, global variables are frowned upon.